# How can I retrieve PPPoe / ADSL password that was saved on Windows?

Tags: adsl, pppoe

How can I retrieve PPPoe / ADSL password that was saved on Windows?

Comment: Please give us more details about this question. That is how you lost it and what you have done that the password was lost. It will be easy for us to understand the situation.

Comment: Easy example: you lost the paper form the ISP and you want to configure the ADSL on another computer or router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does any of the tools described in the links below answer your need :

[Windows Password Recovery Tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html)
[ADSLPwd](http://www.techiedesi.com/post/410-recover-adsl-router-and-modem-passwords-easily-with-adslpwd-utility)

If not, please tell us why.