# Where are RAS (Dial-up / PPP / PPPoE) passwords saved on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, pppoe, credentials, dial-up

I recently replaced the hard drive in a Windows XP system, and installed Windows 7 on a new drive.  The old installation is no longer accessible (I cannot boot to the old XP install).  I did make a full backup of the old drive, though.

I'm trying to set up the PPPoE connection for this system (no router), but the credentials have been long forgotten.

**Where are the username / password for RAS connections stored?**

- Answers for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/253569/how-can-i-retrieve-pppoe-adsl-password-that-was-saved-on-windows) provide only links to utilities, that seem to require online (booted) access.
- [This Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284269) describes how to save/restore connections (via `rasphone.pbk` file), but this does not include the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://www.juniper.net/security/auto/vulnerabilities/vuln232.html) mentions that they are saved in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\RasCredentials!SID#0
```

[*Dialuppass*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html) (linked to by that Nirsoft link from the other question) *does* seem to have an offline facility. It takes a command-line option:

> `/external <Windows Directory> <Profiles Base Folder>`
>
> Load the dialup items from external instance of Windows 2000/XP/2003 operating system. For example: 
>   dialupass.exe /external "j:\windows" "j:\Documents and Settings"

This command-line seems to make sense with the other information provided:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is saved in the Windows directory.
- `rasphone.pbk` is saved in Documents and Settings.